# Absolute moments of order statistics

Tags: probability, order-statistics, expected-value

I had the following question on a test some time ago and was unable to find a solution:

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be i.i.d. with distribution function $F$ such that $E|X|^\alpha<\infty$ for some $\alpha>0$. Let 
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
    r\leq \alpha \min(k,n-k+1).
\end{equation}

How can I show that

\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
    E|X_{(k)}|^r< \infty,
\end{equation}
where $X_{(k)}$ is the $k$-th order statistics?

Any tips on how to start out?

Comment: Great question. What were your own thoughts?